# ubuntu FTP script - hetzner

Tags: shell, ftp, backup, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to backup of my application directory, database backup and then sending it to my ftp server at hetzner by using the following script and I get few errors

My server details: ubuntu12-04 (in hetzner)
database: postgresql8.4
my ftp server: hetzner
Trying to take backup at ubuntu12.04 server and copying in ftp my server
got a sample script at following [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=229943)

bakupscript.sh

```
site=ftp://u***.your-backup.de
username=u***
passwd=*******************
backupdir=/opt/openbravo-erp
filenameob="openbravo-erp.tar.gz"

echo "Creating a ob backup file $filenameob of $backupdir."

# Make a tar gzipped backup file
tar -cvzf /home/hetznerftp/"$filenameob" "$backupdir"

echo "creating a db backup file $filenamedb of ob database."
export PGPASSWORD="*my db password*"
backup_dir="/home/manideep/hetzner/"
#String to append to the name of the backup files
pg_dump -h localhost -U tad openbravo -Fc $i > $backup_dir$i\rajedb.backup

#login into ftp server
ftp -in <<EOF
open $ftp_site
user $username $passwd
bin
put /home/manideep/hetzner$filenameob 
put /home/manideep/hetznerftp/pgdump.backup
close 
bye
EOF
```

When I try executing that script through command `./backupscript.sh`

I get following error

```
Creating a backup file openbravo-erp.tar.gz of /opt/openbravo-erp.
creating a db backup file  of ob database.
(to) usage: open host-name [port]
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
```

How do I send those files through script?

And will this replace the existing files while I use command `put` in `ftp` in `ftp server`
if not, how do I do it?

Comment: Why not use `rsync` ? That way you only copy the files you need to and you don't have to mess around with crusty old FTP.

Comment: See the rsync man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync

Comment: i just tried this command

rsync -avz --progress /home/manideep/hetznerftp/ u*****@u*****.your-backup.de/

and i got this output 

`sending incremental file list
created directory u77751@u77751.your-backup.de
./
openbravo-erp.tar.gz
  1097923138 100%   43.68MB/s    0:00:23 (xfer#1, to-check=1/3)
rajedb.backup
  1969128727 100%   48.57MB/s    0:00:38 (xfer#2, to-check=0/3)

sent 3068081636 bytes  received 53 bytes  48316247.07 bytes/sec
total size is 3067051865  speedup is 1.00

**when i logged into ftp i couldnot find my files**

Comment: if i try this rsync:
`rsync -avzhe ssh /home/manideep/hetznerftp u*****@u*****.your-backup.de`

it is creating a file locally and syncing with it.. not with my ftp server

Comment: You need a `:` after the remote host name, so it would be: `rsync -av /home/manideep/hetznerftp/ u*****@u*****.your-backup.de:<remote path goes here, if needed>/`

Comment: ok ill see look at that

Comment: @PaulR thnx for help but.. i get following error when i did that

`exec request failed on channel 0
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(605) [sender=3.0.9]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second the suggestion by petrus4, lftp is way better suited to scripting than ftp.

The *...usage open host-name...* error and what follows is because you use the variable $site_ftp which is empty. The variable you set is $site. And if you do it with the open command, you must remove the ftp:// prefix.

The warning about line 21 is because you use a here document with *<<EOF* which means "use everything what follows as input until you find a line which reads *EOF*". But you don't have a line which reads *EOF*.

By the way, sshfs works very nicely with hetzner backup space. With sshfs, you can mount the backup space as if it was a partition. VERY easy to use.

Comment: ive made the necessary changes u said.. but its not wokring.. error was gone.. but it still says 
`(to) usage: open host-name [port]
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.
Not connected.`

Answer (score 0):

Get lftp.  http://lftp.yar.ru/

The script you have written will probably work with that.